# How to pass data from one controller to another controller in ONSEN UI angular?

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

i have a html like below

```
<a class="event_detail_btn_a" ng-click="foo()"></a>
```

following is my controller

```
    onsenApp.controller("EventDetailController", function ($scope) {
        $scope.foo = function(){
            alert("foo!");
            var options = {
                data: {
                    title: 'Another Page'
                }
            };

        };
});
```

i want to pass "options" variable to another controller from this controller.
how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [$broadcast](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) to pass data between controllers.

In the example `add()` is defined in `Controller1` which is passed to `Controller2` after 2 secs.

```js
angular
  .module("app", [])
  .controller("Controller1", function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout){
    var add = function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    }
    
    $timeout(function(){
      $rootScope.$broadcast("Add function", add);
    }, 2000);
  })
  .controller("Controller2", function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout){
    $scope.$on("Add function", function(event, add) {
      $scope.sum = add(3, 4);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Controller1">
    <span>Add function defined in Controller1</span><br /><br />
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="Controller2">
    <span ng-show="sum">3 + 4 = {{ sum }}</span>
    <span ng-show="!sum">Controller2 waiting for add function...</span><br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to create a `service` OR a `factory` and inject in both controllers like below:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('MyService', function() {
  var options = {
    data: {
      title: 'Another Page'
    }
  };
  return {
    options
  };
});

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, MyService) {
  $scope.options = MyService.options;
});

myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, MyService) {
  $scope.options = MyService.options;
});
```

Comment: how to set data ?

Comment: @MDTAHMIDHOSSAIN, updated the answer to set data i.e. options

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass data to another controller, the way i am getting it is :

```
onsenApp.controller("EventDetailController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.foo = function(){
        alert("foo!");
        var options = {
            data: {
                title: 'Another Page'
            }
        };
```

this is one way you can achieve this using event push-page with it you send data.

```
     myNavigator.pushPage('xyz.html', 
        {myData: options} );
  }
    };

 });

onsenApp.controller("SecondController", function ($scope) {
```

here you can get your desired data

```
$scope.options =  myNavigator.getCurrentPage().options.myData;

});
```